# Project Reactor and the Java memory model

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to understand what guarantees with respect to data visibility Project reactor provides to application code. For e.g. I would expect the below code to fail but it does not after a million iterations. I am changing the state of a typical POJO on thread A and reading it back from thread B. Does Reactor guarantee POJO changes are visible across thread?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer result = Flux.range(1, 1_000_000)
                .map(i -> {
                    Data data = new Data();
                    data.setValue(i);
                    data.setValueThreeTimes(i);
                    data.setValueObj(i + i);
                    return data;
                })
                .parallel(250)
                .runOn(Schedulers.newParallel("par", 500))
                .map(d -> {
                    d.setValueThreeTimes(d.getValueThreeTimes() + d.getValue());
                    return d;
                })
                .sequential()
                .parallel(250)
                .runOn(Schedulers.newParallel("par", 500))
                .map(d -> {
                    d.setValueThreeTimes(d.getValueThreeTimes() + d.getValue());
                    return d;
                })
                //                .sequential()
                .map(d -> {
                    if (d.getValue() * 3 != d.getValueThreeTimes()) throw new RuntimeException("data corrupt error");
                    return d;
                })
                .reduce(() -> 0, (Integer sum, Data d) -> sum + d.getValueObj() + d.getValue())
                .sequential()
                .blockLast();
    }

    static class Data {
        private int value;
        private int valueThreeTimes;
        private Integer valueObj;

        public int getValueThreeTimes() {
            return valueThreeTimes;
        }

        public void setValueThreeTimes(int valueThreeTimes) {
            this.valueThreeTimes = valueThreeTimes;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data{" +
                    "value=" + value +
                    ", valueObj=" + valueObj +
                    '}';
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Integer getValueObj() {
            return valueObj;
        }

        public void setValueObj(Integer valueObj) {
            this.valueObj = valueObj;
        }
    }

    private static <T> T identityWithThreadLogging(T el, String operation) {
        System.out.println(operation + " -- " + el + " -- " +
                Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return el;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `sequential` from the chain?

Comment: Just tried without `sequential`. Returns the correct result. It seems like there's a memory fence being applied when elements move from one operator to the next.

Comment: Idk the implementation, but maybe steps are sequential and particular operation in step are parallel - thus your "barrier"

Answer (score 3):

The Reactive Streams specification enforces that for a `Flux` or `Mono` (a `Publisher`), `onNext` events must be sequential.

`parallel()` is a `ParallelFlux`, which relaxes that a bit by dividing-and-conquering: you get multiple "rails" that each individually stick to the spec, but overall do not (parallelisation between rails).

In turn, `sequential()` goes back to the `Flux` world and introduces memory barrier to guarantee the resulting sequence complies with the RS spec.

Comment: If I were to create a simple POJO & call a few setters in a map stage and then start processing on `parallel` rails, will the values from the setter invocation be visible in the parallel rails? Do we have to use volatile or final fields when using reactor to get a consistent view of data as it changes within a stream?

Comment: Stages before the parallel() one will either execute on the same thread or use volatile to trigger memory barriers