# Correct use of mutable mongodb entities in reactive (webflux) application

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

Current spring-data-mongodb project uses mutable entities to load state from database even in reactive application. It is considered a bad practice and I can find some issues even in the spring-data-mongodb project itself. For example code snippet from ReactiveMongoTemplate:

```
protected <T> Mono<T> doSave(String collectionName, T objectToSave, MongoWriter<Object> writer) {

    assertUpdateableIdIfNotSet(objectToSave);

    return createMono(collectionName, collection -> {

        T toSave = maybeEmitEvent(new BeforeConvertEvent<T>(objectToSave, collectionName)).getSource();

        AdaptibleEntity<T> entity = operations.forEntity(toSave, mongoConverter.getConversionService());
        Document dbDoc = entity.toMappedDocument(writer).getDocument();
        maybeEmitEvent(new BeforeSaveEvent<T>(toSave, dbDoc, collectionName));

        return saveDocument(collectionName, dbDoc, toSave.getClass()).map(id -> {

            T saved = entity.populateIdIfNecessary(id);
            return maybeEmitEvent(new AfterSaveEvent<>(saved, dbDoc, collectionName)).getSource();
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see entity.populateIdIfNecessary(id) is mutating entity object on another thread, which is considered  a bug in multithreaded application, unless you use entity where all setters are synchronized.

What is the correct and recomended practice to deal with concurrency issues using mutable entities with reactive mongodb interface?
Consider this example:

```
reactiveMongoOperations.findById("id2", Customer.class) // calls Customer setters on thread1
  .zipWith(reactiveMongoOperations.findById("id2", Account.class)) // calls Account setters on thread2
  .map(t -> perform(t.getT1(), t.getT2())); // access objects on thread2
```

To make this code safe, you need to have immutable Customer and Account classes (which spring data mongodb desnot support), or all setter must be synchronized/volatile witch makes your code very thread-aware and error prone.

Comment: What makes you think there are concurrency issues with that? Can you show an example of such a problem happening? Reactor operators are already dealing with concurrency and provide guarantee about the order of execution and concurrency. Same thing happens with HTTP requests and responses in Spring WebFlux, yet no such concurrency issue is happening.

Comment: Reactor does not solve concurrent memory access issues in your data objects. If you set value to a variable, it may not be visible yet in another thread unless that field is final/volatile or field access is put in synchronized block. That is the basics of how concurrent memory access is implemented in jvm. Reactor does not put anything in synchronized block, that means you data object has to be either final, or fields defined as volatile. In my example you are zipping two Mono objects that may return results from two different threads.

Comment: Reactive streams guarantees that operators are applied sequentially on emitted elements. If you decide to mutate elements out of that scope it’s on you but your code snippet doesn’t show any of that. Could you improve the question and simplify the code snippet to underline the actual problem?

Comment: reactiveMongoOperations instantiates Account and Customer objects, then mutates them (calls setters). That's how spring-data-mongo works as I understand. My concern is that in the process() method event if I use read only access I may run into concurrency issues, because Account and Customer may be instantiated (and mutated) in different threads. So even if operators are applied sequentially, those operations may be performed on different threads and our data objects still must be thread safe. I've added comments in my second snippet.

Comment: Basically my concern is about reordering in java memory model when data is modified in two different threads https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found similar question with the answers about project reactor and memory model [Project Reactor and the Java memory model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106835/project-reactor-and-the-java-memory-model) . So it seems that if you are not using parallel operator, memory consistency is guaranteed using memory barriers (volatile keywords).

Comment: Also a good discussion here https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/issues/53